# Wrong Display in Line Symbol and Gradient Color

Tags: arcgis-server, symbology, line, arcgis-silverlight-api, silverlight

I create a line symbol with specific gradient color and below control template:

```
<ControlTemplate>
        <Path  x:Name='Element'   StrokeThickness='10' UseLayoutRounding='False' StrokeStartLineCap='Round' StrokeEndLineCap='Round' StrokeDashCap='Round' StrokeLineJoin='Round'  RenderTransformOrigin='0.5,0.5' StrokeDashArray='0' Stretch='Fill' >
            <Path.Stroke>
                <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin='8,0' Center='0,0' RadiusX='-4.5'>
                    <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform CenterY='0.5' CenterX='0.5' />
                    </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    <GradientStop Color='Transparent' Offset='0.588'/>
                    <GradientStop Color='Red' Offset='1'/>
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </Path.Stroke>
        </Path>
</ControlTemplate>
```

[Line in blend](http://postimg.org/image/9ybw07xs7/)

and result is:

[Line Symbol in map](http://postimg.org/image/mrytfbukx/)

What does reason of bad diplay in gradient color?